# MYSQL search returning incorrect results when using whole model numbers

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query which contains sample data for a product with the model number of HA/200

When searching for the model number, no results are returned for that specific product but other products are included.

If however I search for HA/ then the HA/200 product is listed, and is actually the heaviest weighted search result.

I'm struggling to see why HA/ will return the HA/200, but HA/200 will not.
It's got me most perplexed. Any suggestions from the below sql query??

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.products_model,
    p.products_image,
    p.products_quantity,
    m.manufacturers_id,
    p.products_id,
    pd.products_name,
    p.products_price,
    p.products_tax_class_id,
    p.products_price_sorter,
    p.products_qty_box_status,
    p.master_categories_id,
    IF (
        p.products_model LIKE "HA/200",
        1050, 
        IF( 
            p.products_model LIKE "%HA/200%",
            700,
            0
        ) + IF (
            MATCH(pd.products_name, pd.products_description) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s"),
            MATCH(pd.products_name, pd.products_description) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s") * 10,
            0
        )
    ) + IF (
        MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s"),
        MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s") * 5,
        0
    ) + IF (
        MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s"),
        MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("HA/200 HA/200s") * 700,
        0
    ) + (pd.products_viewed / 8206.421) as weight 
FROM (
    products p LEFT JOIN manufacturers m USING(manufacturers_id),
    products_description pd,
    categories c,
    products_to_categories p2c
)
LEFT JOIN meta_tags_products_description mtpd
    ON mtpd.products_id= p2c.products_id AND mtpd.language_id = 1 
WHERE (
    p.products_status = 1 
    AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
    AND pd.language_id = 1 
    AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
    AND p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id  
    AND (
        MATCH(p.products_model, pd.products_description) AGAINST("HA/200* HA/200s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        OR MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("HA/200* HA/200s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        OR MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("HA/200* HA/200s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        OR MATCH(mtpd.metatags_keywords, mtpd.metatags_description) AGAINST("HA/200* HA/200s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    )
)
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

Comment: I've discovered that removing the entire bottom section of the query related to IN BOOLEAN MODE makes the HA/200 show up as the first result. However, I suspect this is going to have negative impact elsewhere. What is the purpose of the IN BOOLEAN MODE command and why does it's existence prevent a direct match from being displayed in the results?

Comment: From what I've found online, it would appear that there are issues when an / is encountered in a BOOLEAN MODE search. Is this something anyone of you has experienced and found a fix for?